# SQL: How to select full rows in each group which matched conditions on some fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have one table in postgresql database, for example:

[image]

Is there any way to get result as below output with good performance? That means in each group I want get full of rows which matched with some conditions,  such as userid=100, also add more fields by aggregate functions

***Output (with userid=100 as the condition I want, or other condition):***

[image]

***Note: The data is dynamically, such as the content, seen... field are random***

I have used this SQL query, but it only can two fields:

```
SELECT  groupid, 
        string_agg(text(userid), ', ') AS lst_userids,
FROM  t1
GROUP BY groupid
```

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: On what basis you are choosing the other columns ? example, for `Groupid : 2000` why did you choose `a` as `content` instead of `b` ?

Comment: that based on field 'userid', that means all columns of row has userid=100 for example

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT min(id) as id, groupid, 
       string_agg(text(userid), ', ') AS lst_userids,
       max(case when seen then content end) as content,
       bool_or(seen) as seen
FROM t1
GROUP BY groupid;
```

I am guessing what the actual logic is, but you can definitely have multiple columns in an aggregation query.

Comment: uhm, your query is for the data specified as above, but I want based on some condition on some field such as userid=100 or other condition